# Error in instantiating a method in test class

Tags: unit-test, error

How to instantiate this method in test class?

My apex class looks as below..

```
public static List<object> getOP(){

    User u = [SELECT Name,AccountId FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
    List<object> OP = [SELECT Id,Name,account__c from object 
                                    WHERE account__c = :u.AccountId];

    return OP;
}
```

in test method I am using below statement to instantiate above method.

```
getOP olrp = new getOP();
```

But I receive this error

> error Invalid type:getOP

Comment: Well, `getOP` is a method, not a type. You can't instantiate it. You can call it like this: `List<object> yourObjects = Your_Class_Name.getOP();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to read [Static and Instance Methods, Variables, and Initialization Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm). Only classes can be instantiated, and only if they're not abstract. Instance methods are called using an instance of a class, and static methods are called by using the static reference `ClassName.methodName`.